# How to animate div height smoothly automatically

Tags: jquery, css, animation, html

I know the jQuery `animate` function, and I can change the divs height with that smoothly, but the question is:

I have a div:

```
<div class="blah">Content with 3 lines</div>
```

And then I append some more lines to the above div using jQuery, the div height is `auto` so it's gonna go longer, but not smoothly, is there anyway it could go longer smoothly like using jQuery `animate` function?

**I just don't want to type animate({blah}) on any appends, ajax calls, etc..**

***Is it possible to have a function to get called on every divs `height changes`? and deal with it using `animate` function?***

I have also read about transitions, so I did:

```
.blah{
    -webkit-transition: height 1s ease-in-out !important;
    -moz-transition: height 1s ease-in-out !important;
    -ms-transition: height 1s ease-in-out !important;
    -o-transition: height 1s ease-in-out !important;
    transition: height 1s ease-in-out !important;
}
```

but not working

The jQuery method, which appends data:

```
$('blah').append('<p style="clear:both;">Another Line</p>')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you change the order and then try: animate height, then append?

Comment: Isnt a transition time suppose to ne in th master class and effects in transition classes?? I'm not too familiar with CSS3 animation, but I've seen almost all that way

Comment: You could append the data in <span>'s or something like that and animate those at creation, but without calling an animate method any how?... Interesting question, really, I stay tuned ;-) I don't see a solution in CSS3

Comment: @pc-shooter I'm working on something, what if we have a function which get called on every div `height changes`, and do it with `animate` ?

Comment: That should work, but you said, that you don't want to call the animate on every append, ajax, etc

Comment: @pc-shooter I meant not every time I type `animate({blah, blah})`, this needs to deal with `animate` function anyway, or some css `transitions` trick!?

Comment: Can you show the jquery code where you append data ?

Comment: @pc-shooter `$('blah').append('<p style="clear:both;">Another Line</p>')`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51059/discussion-between-pc-shooter-and-behz4d)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/zwvNY/1935/)**</kbd>

jQuery

```
$("#blah")
    .hide()
    .html('<p>Another Line</p><p>Another Line</p><p>Another Line</p>')
    .slideDown('slow');
```

CSS

```
div {
    background:slategray;
    color:white;
    padding:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but it is better to create a global function with animating a height or try pc-shooter method.

```
 $(blah).change(function() { // Do something });
```

And maybe this can help you: http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/Pb6FF/

Comment: @gbehz4d After chatting with you and as far i understood you, the jsfiddle linked here is my preferred answer so far.

Comment: @pc-shooter I'm surprised, it has nothing to do with my question!

Comment: @behz4d it just changes the css-class (with transition) in ONE call. Isn' that what you wanted?

Comment: @pc-shooter definitely not

Answer (score 0):

The `height:auto` will not work with **CSS transition**

A height must be defined (*px* or *percentage*, rather than auto) to make the transition work.

You might want to add this on your JavaScript

```
// Get the height of 'blah' from document
heightOfBlah = $('.blah').height();

// Set the height of 'blah' explicitly
$('.blah').css('height', heightOfBlah);
```

After setting this explicitly, the CSS transition will work.

Comment: How are you adding contents to your div? Can you share the JS code with a fiddle?

Comment: imagine a simple jquery append: `$('blah').append('<p style="clear:both;">Another Line</p>')`